# How to disable Chrome logging messages?

Tags: webview, nativescript, chromium

I'm using webview and get a lot of messages like

`chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(50)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0`

How can I disable it?

Comment: Logging is disabled by default in Chrome and Chromium. You can go to this page `chrome://version/` and then look at the values of `Command Line`. Do you see `--enable-logging`? If it's there then logging is enabled

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter for these messages to the Nativescript log filter functions similar to what's done in https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/3727